# Problems with using google fonts in iphone

Tags: html, css, google-font-api, google-fonts

I am now creating a website using NotoSans by importing a linked stylesheet on my website. It worked fine on windows and android. My website contains simplified chinese and traditional chinese.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+SC|Noto+Sans+TC" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, it does not work on iphone for all browsers. All the preceding character of the order list are not shown properly. Below is the demo of the situation(unorder list in the demo but order list in my website).

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: do you have any css with `font-family` ? please show us

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kf4h0pL2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dzwe8qro/1/
This is my code

Comment: you use `il` instead `li`(typo error):https://jsfiddle.net/tef4buhn/

Comment: Oh Thanks!
But the code I posted is the demo only. In my website, it should be correct.
Below is the edited version of the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/dzwe8qro/2/

Comment: if you do not use this font what's happend?

Comment: There will be no problem if I remove the linked stylesheet.

Comment: But I would like to use this font style. Are there any solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed.
I have added the code below in my css

```
webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1, dlig=1";
-ms-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
```